# Failed to load PDF document (MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008

[image]Please help. It shows **"Failed to load PDF document"**.

I didn't find where I mistake in code.

This is my code:

View:

```
<a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="View" href="@Url.Action("DownloadFile", new { id = pat.ID })" target="_blank" class=" btn btn-success btn-sm">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
```

Controller:

```
public FileStreamResult DownloadFile(int id)
{
    MemoryStream workStream = new MemoryStream();
    DataModel DB = new DataModel();
    /var content = DB._PATIENT.Where(m => m.ID == id).FirstOrDefault();
    byte[] contents = (byte[])content.Result;
    workStream.Write(contents, 0, contents.Length);
    workStream.Position = 0;

    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=someFile.pdf");
    return new FileStreamResult(workStream, "application/pdf");    
}
```

Model:

```
public int ID { get; set; }
public string PatientCode { get; set; }
public string CaseNo { get; set; }
public DateTime DatePerformed { get; set; }
public byte[] Result { get; set; }
public DateTime ExpirationDate { get; set; }
public string LaboratoryName { get; set; }
```

Comment: Could you please post your error message?

Comment: Is it a valid pdf bytes returned here, `byte[] contents = (byte[])content.Result;` ?

Comment: @Aruna, yes it is valid.

Comment: @LuisTeijon, please try my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that `content.Result` is already a byte array of the pdf then just return the byte array.

```
public ActionResult DownloadFile(int id) {
    var DB = new DataModel();
    var patient = DB._PATIENT.Where(m => m.ID == id).FirstOrDefault();
    if (patient != null && patient.Result != null && patient.Result.Length > 0) {
        var content = patient.Result; //this is a byte[] of the pdf
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=someFile.pdf");
        return File(content, "application/pdf");
    }
    return RedirectToAction("BadPatientFile");
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Still getting the error: "Failed to load PDF document".

Comment: Then your byte array probably has corrupt data.

Comment: Try it in other browsers as well to make sure it is not browser specific.

Comment: I already try it on the other browser, same error. I guess you're right maybe the data is corrupted.

Comment: Try extracting the file and opening it on the desktop rather than the browser. if the desktop client fails then for sure the file is corrupted.

Comment: You're right my data is corrupted and your code also works. Thank you. @Nkosi

Answer (score 0):

Can you return [FileContentResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filecontentresult%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) instead of `FileStreamResult` as below,

```
public ActionResult DownloadFile(int id)
 {
  MemoryStream workStream = new MemoryStream();
  DataModel DB = new DataModel();
  var content = DB._PATIENT.Where(m => m.ID == id).FirstOrDefault();
  byte[] contents = (byte[])content.Result;
  workStream.Write(contents, 0, contents.Length);
  workStream.Position = 0;

  Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=someFile.pdf");
  return File(workStream, "application/pdf", "someFile.pdf");
}
```

Comment: Hello, I get the following error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.RedirectToRouteResult' to 'System.Web.Mvc.FileContentResult'.

Comment: Try the return type as `ActionResult `. I have edited the code above.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I got this error: The localhost page isn’t working

localhost sent an invalid response.
ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_MULTIPLE_CONTENT_DISPOSITION